# Starting out with ads on iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, iad

I'd like a couple of pointers on what the best way is to monetise iOS apps with ads. All of the reviews/tutorials I've found have been from quite a long time ago.

I have a couple of paid apps that I want to use as guinea pigs for free/ad-supported apps. It seems as though an obvious choice would be with iAds, but there are so many other providers that I am unsure on which is the best way to set up an ad-supported app.

**My main question is**, is it best to go with stock iAds or look somewhere else? I've found websites such as [topmobileadnetworks](http://www.topmobileadnetworks.com) that suggest using services such as [LeadBolt](http://www.leadboltnetwork.net) for serving iOS ads.

Does anyone have any tips or best-practices/services/sdks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `IAds` and others using `iAd Delegate` :

Example For the google `AdMob`

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

[self.bannerView removeFromSuperview];
[bannerView removeFromSuperview];
if ( admobBannerView!=nil) {
    [ admobBannerView removeFromSuperview];
    admobBannerView=nil;
}

admobBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape];
admobBannerView.adUnitID =  @"adUnitID";
admobBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0, admobBannerView.frame.size.width, admobBannerView.frame.size.height);
admobBannerView.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:admobBannerView];
[admobBannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this snippet if I decide to go with `iAds`! However, I was more interested in if `iAds` are worth using in the first place over competitors such as `AdMob`?

Comment: if you have a lot of users, YES its worthing, Especially iAds